# Importing an existing Java Package(Own created package) into another Project. NetBeans 8.1 IDE

Tags: java, package, netbeans-8

We know that we can make and import our own package in java in the same project which we have created in NetBeans but how to import a package/packages that are created for a project to another project or how to use the created packages for a project from another project.

Comment: Check out this question if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/10315597/3503187

Comment: Create a jar file of the project you need to import the packages from and include in new project

Comment: How to do this please explain

Comment: Learn to use Maven or Gradle; it will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just make the .jar file of that/those java files which you want to use in another project. right click on file->export->java->.jar then finish.

Now you can use these jar into your another project.

Comment: I am using Netbean 8.1

Comment: I can't find Java Build Path in properties if you are using Netbeans please post screenshot

Comment: There is no such type of option, I also head to the File under the menu bar there is an export option but this option is only to convert to ZIP not to jar. Post a screenshot with your answer. I am using Neatbean 8.1.

Comment: if have a zip file just name to jar and so could use it accordigly  or use an online converts to attain your solution https://convertio.co/zip-jar/ @greek

Comment: Is there no way to do it using Netbean

Comment: not sure with the IDE version you are using still hope ans helps  @geek